# Where to find healthcare practice and hospital names?

Tags: data-request, usa, medical

I can get all physician data in the US from the NPI registry. But it doesn't contain the practice names (or the hospital names). Is there a place I can get these?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking at doing something similar with the Provider ID. I haven't found a clean dataset that'll tie it all together, but there is this  [list of hospital general information from CMS](https://data.medicare.gov/Hospital-Compare/Hospital-General-Information/xubh-q36u) to do a fuzzy match to the address of the hospital and the doctor to do a weak tie.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this for a while, but when I was coming up with lists of medical practices, these are the places I looked:

- [Medicare Utiliation](https://data.cms.gov/Medicare-Physician-Supplier/Medicare-Provider-Utilization-and-Payment-Data-Phy/sk9b-znav)
- [SAMHSA](https://findtreatment.samhsa.gov/) (You may need to FOIA the dataset that powers the treatment locator.)
- State licensing agencies ([Illinois, for example](https://www.idfpr.com/applications/professionprofile/default.aspx))